# Windows 11 notification badge counter is gone with the 23H2 update

Tags: windows-11, notifications

So I installed the 23H2 update and now the notification badge counter in the taskbar is gone:

[image]

You can see it shows a rectangle. Not even sure what it represents. I'm on version 23H2 build number 22631.2506.

It won't show any number whether you have a notification or not.

Any solutions to bring the number back? I couldn't find any setting relevant to this.

Comment: Which update have you installed? Are you on the Insider channel? ([link](https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/microsoft-is-changing-how-notifications-appear-on-the-windows-11-taskbar))

Comment: @harrymc I don't think I'm on the Insider channel. I edited my post and added the update history image.

Comment: @xperator - What is the value of TaskbarBadges?

Comment: I would start by removing KB5030310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also suffered this problem, and the reason was that an old version of Segoe Fluent Icons font file exists in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts` (I don't know why.)

I deleted the file `SEGOEICONS.TTF` (and all duplicated fonts) in the folder (you may need safe mode) and all font problems solved.

Comment: Thank you so much! I could never guess it was a font issue. Although deleting that file isn't directly possible. I found an alternative solution on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/16teb2h/just_updated_my_windows_11_what_is_this_square/

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft article
[Microsoft is changing how notifications appear on the Windows 11 Taskbar](https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/microsoft-is-changing-how-notifications-appear-on-the-windows-11-taskbar),
the counter is gone for good and is not returning.

The article describes an Insider channel version, where the counter was
replaced by a bell icon which is displayed as filled when notifications
are available:

[image]

Apparently, the update with the bell icon has not reached the
Stable channel yet.
It might arrive in the future, but for the moment the icon that is
displayed is not informative.

You may try to test Windows integrity by running the commands
[Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
and then
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).
But if no errors are found, then your current situation cannot
be fixed.